# Computer bluescreen-ing with 0x7A and 0xF4 errors

Tags: windows, bsod

This computer is locking up for around 5-30 seconds before throwing Blue Screen of Death's with 0x7A and occasionally 0xF4 errors. The log files don't really show anything informative, and Windows Update doesn't show any new drivers for the HDD. Upon restart, it shows a "A disk error has occurred /n Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to continue", and to fix this I go into WinRE via the pendrive and run "bootsect /nt60 C: /force /mbr" and that seems to fix it so it boots. And then the cycle repeats.

If you want any more information please ask.

Thanks,
Luke Carpenter

Comment: You can use BlueScreenView to analyze the dumps and add the info to your post : http://nirsoft.net/utils/blue%5Fscreen%5Fview.html

Comment: Thanks very much for this tool, but I have no idea how to interpret the data that it shows me.
UPDATE: Right-click, properties shows that it was caused by "ntoskrnl.exe" and "ntoskrnl.exe+70740" for where it happened.

Comment: [`ntoskrnl.exe`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntoskrnl) is part of the Windows kernal.

Comment: Take screenshots from BlueScreenView for several aborts and add to your post, like the first image on the BlueScreenView site (and especially the lines in rose-color). Also double-click the .dmp and add a screenshot of the Properties.

Answer (score 0):

A [`STOP 0x7A`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559211) is a `KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR`, which roughly means that a page of kernel data was not found where it should be in the paging file and/or couldn't be loaded to memory.

A [`STOP 0xF4`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560372) is a `CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION`, which is much less useful but means a system critical process or thread has unexpectedly stopped.

So, you're potentially looking at hardware problems - maybe a dying hard drive, particularly given the message you get next boot. Check the SMART status of your drive, and for bad sectors, as soon as possible. Run `chkdsk`.

It could also be a RAM fault, so a memory scan is probably a good idea.

You may wish to refresh your backups before doing any of this.

Comment: I don't have anything large enough to back up the 300-350GB of data on the spare partition. I have run chkdsk multiple times and it gives a clean bill of health every time. I took pictures of both errors, the F4 error has these in brackets: 0x(athousandzeroshere)3, 0xFFFFFAB002C01060, 0xFFFFFA8002C01340, 0xFFFFF80002D8B500
The 0x7A has 0xFFFFF6FC50020F78, 0xFFFFFFFFC0000185, 0x000000000EB19820, 0XFFFFF8A0041EFBF2.
Thanks very much for your time,
Luke

Comment: @lcarpenter The 2nd value for `0x7a` (`0x...185`) indicates `STATUS_IO_DEVICE_ERROR` - which means "improper termination, defective storage controller hardware, or defective disk cabling, or two devices attempting to use the same resources". Have you checked for loose connections inside the machine? I'm having difficulty finding the parameter info for `0xF4`...

Comment: @lcarpenter Do a memory check as well - it might be the RAM at fault.

Comment: The system bluescreened again, however because I swapped to minidump's over kernel dumps it went too quickly, however it say "ntfs.sys"  

The system is stuck at a post-POST screen with "DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER"  

Ouch :(  

Luke

Comment: @lcarpenter - Ah. Not good. If you're *sure* of the integrity of the drive (as it's already passed `chkdsk`, but try checking SMART as well if you get the opportunity) and since you're now getting issues here, then it looks like the issue is becoming more likely to be a faulty connection, a failing hard drive controller, or the motherboard.

Comment: Where would I go to check the SMART functionality?


I asked chkdsk for help and ran it with as many intensive options as possible. Currently "verifying file data" at 19%, running very very slowly.

Comment: @lcarpenter SMART usually requires extra software, but the drive records lots of stats (including warnings, etc). It might be that it is getting bad sectors, but is re-mapping them (so chkdsk doesn't see them). Try [HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com/) or [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) for reading the info.